# Can't seem to center my menu

Tags: html, css

I have done this code for a bit of extra study but I can't seem to center the work and I'm not to sure if I need so much code feel like some should be removed, please help!

If some of the code needs to be taken away I understand just dont quite understand and I feel like everything I Read make me more lost and Just keep changing my code with no solution :(

```
#menubar{
    background:#3399CC;
    height:120px;
}

#menubarwrap {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:100%;
}

#navigationbar-main {
    float:left;
    padding:15px;
    color:#000;
    font-size:24px;
    font-weight:bold;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    text-align:center;
}

#navigationbar-main li {
    margin-right:35px;
    position:relative;
}

#navigationbar-main li a {
    display:block;
    color:#000;
}

#navigationbar-main li ul  {
    display:none;
    z-index:80;
}



.nav-sec {
    display:block;
    font-size:12px;
    font-family: lucida sans unicode;
    font-weight:normal;
    text-align:center;
}
```

HTML

```
<body>


 <div id="menubar">
  <div id="menubarwrap">
     <ul id="navigationbar-main">
          <li><a href="">Home</a><span class="nav-sec">Where We Start</span></li>
          <li><a href="">Gallery</a><span class="nav-sec">Pure Beauty</span></li>
          <li><a href="">Contact</a><span class="nav-sec">Come Book</span></li>
          <li><a href="">Features</a><span class="nav-sec">Pure Luxury</span></li>
          <li><a href="">Location</a><span class="nav-sec">Where Are We?</span></li>
          <li><a href="">Rates</a><span class="nav-sec">Price Of Love</span></li>
      </ul>
  </div>
 </div>


</body>
```

sorry I'm just fairly new to all this

Comment: could you pls paste your html too? thanks!

Comment: sorry mate I thought it was a issue with the css

Comment: could be, but without the HTML, you can do whatever to CSS, it won't matter

Comment: i've tested your code and it does center, aren't you rather looking for it to look like a real navigation menu? is that what you're looking for? Here is the fiddle I created to test this [http://jsfiddle.net/vbG5N/](http://jsfiddle.net/vbG5N/)

Comment: thank you for your help man just had a bad day of this just need to focus more thanks again

Answer (score 1):

I am providing with two solutions guessing its what you need:

### [Fiddle 1](http://jsfiddle.net/Wqn26/)

**Change**

```
#navigationbar-main {
    margin:0px auto;
    /*removed float
    Other styles remain same*/
}
```

---

### [Fiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/Wqn26/1/)

**Change**

```
#navigationbar-main li {
    display:inline-block;
    /*Other styles remain same*/
}
```

Comment: thank you i must have just removed the inline-block because had it up before thats my bad but i thought I got rid of the float left guess not think I am losing my mind think you so much everyone

Comment: Glad to help.BTW if it helped you do accept the answer

Comment: I'm trying i need more reputation im sorry

Comment: For accepting you dont need more reputation.Reputation is needed for vote up

Answer (score 1):

change your ul css

```
 #navigationbar-main {
color: #000000;
font-size: 24px;
font-weight: bold;
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0 auto 10px;
padding: 15px;
text-align: center;
width: 1000px;
}
```

and give flat:left to your li

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to center align the `#navigationbar-main ul`, do this

```
#navigationbar-main ul{
    float:left /*remove this line*/
}
```

This will get you the `ul` to the center of the page horizontally.
And if you want to align the `li` items horizontally apply this:

```
#navigationbar-main li {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#navigationbar-main {
   width: 100%;
}
```

Add this to your CSS,